# partial loop in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, partials

I am trying to print some products using partial loops in Zend Framework. I am using this code in my view:

```
echo $this->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('product') >partialLoop('/_loops/singleProduct.phtml', $this->last_products);
```

It works, but I don't know how to use that parameter **$this->last_products**. I tried in singleProduct.php this code:

```
echo $this->product['name'];
```

but I've got an error:
`Notice: Key "product" does not exist in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/View/Abstract.php on line 270`

Actually, what I am triyng to write is **$this->last_products['name']**, but because I have **partialLoop()->setObjectKey('product')** I tought this is how it works. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of thing is `$this->last_products`? Is it an array?

Comment: Yes it an array. I've done a SELECT from DB and put the result there. So if I want to print the name of the product in view I must write `echo $this->last_products['name'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it using `$this->name`

Comment: I need 15 reputation. Help me get there and I'll you give up vote as well :)